# Monkey is not giving output: No activity found to run, Monkey aborted

Tags: android, testing, android-monkey

I am new to Monkey testing tool, it says run the following command

> adb shell monkey -p "package name" -v 3

It is not clear to me whether to pass this command from inside the Project Directory or from the workspace where my Project is present.

Each time I run I get the following error

> :Monkey: seed=0 count=3
>   :AllowPackage: com.and
>   :IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   :IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
>   ** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check that you don't have `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` anywhere in your gradle file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running a command using `adb shell`, the command is run on the connected Android device or emulator. So the current working directory for the command would be that of the device. How would it matter whether you execute it "from inside the Project Directory or from the workspace where my Project is present"?

Looking at the error you got, it's clear that you've not given the allowed package name correctly.

Comment: yes , I was not giving the package name correctly. Can you suggest me how to pass rotation event while testing through monkey tool

Answer (score 2):

Check your application whether it has an Activity (android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)or not in manifest file. If its not present you will get this error. Actually i am also testing mobile apps with monkey tool and got this error. If you have any doubt create a sample project with Activity & intent filter and run monkey tool.

Comment: Do you know how to pass rotation event while testing through monkey tool.

Comment: I think so possible/not by monkey tool because it is a pseudo random events. and also check with below link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/9OktySxjoNA/kUS4WVJhBIsJ

Comment: Just now tested with ICS device, Orientation happens when do manually while doing manually.:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(41.0,741.0)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(38.0403,748.6024)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(370.0,478.0)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(377.42416,477.805)

:Sending Flip keyboardOpen=true

Comment: After spending some time just found something but i didnt tried this cmd->  adb shell monkey -p<package name> --pct-flip<percentage> -v 500                                                                    :Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(41.0,741.0)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(38.0403,748.6024)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(370.0,478.0)

:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(377.42416,477.805)

:Sending Flip keyboardOpen=true