# Error in monkey test android

Tags: android, monkey

I want to test my apk (package name : com.edutor.ignitor) with monkey. So i typed the following command

```
adb shell monkey -p com.edutor.ignitor -v 200
```

getting error as follows

```
:Monkey: seed=1403140033385 count=200
:AllowPackage: com.edutor.ignitor
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

Next i typed the following command

```
adb shell monkey -p com.edutor.ignitor -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -vvv 100
```

getting error as follows

```
:Monkey: seed=1403155767105 count=100
:AllowPackage: com.edutor.ignitor
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

Any suggestions ..?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838159/monkey-is-not-giving-output-no-activity-found-to-run-monkey-aborted

Comment: Hi manu, thanks for the reply... My package name is correct. Even it is giving the same error

Comment: Is your Launcher-Activity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: do we need to mention any permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: No, but you have to declare it as launcher-activity. In your  AndroidManifest.xml `<application>` -> `<activity>`-Tag for your launcher activity, there's another tag called `<intent-filter>`. Do you have the tag `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` as well as `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in there?

Comment: In my Androidmanifest.xml , i have only <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> but not having <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: try adding the LAUNCHER tag, then try to run it again

Comment: As u said , i added the tag <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in my manifest file but getting the same error.

Comment: Be sure you've previously installed the APK into the device: `adb install your_apk.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of entering the seed value, monkey has no executable event, plus the seed value, which is set to 20, such as:

```
adb shell monkey -p om.edutor. Ignitor-s 20-v-v-v 200
```